# In what year was asteroid Donaldjohanson chosen as a target for Lucy?

Tags: asteroid, lucy-asteroid-mission

[Asteroid 52246 Donaldjohanson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/52246_Donaldjohanson) was officially named in 2015. Was it chosen as a target for Lucy before being named?

Comment: potentially interesting factoid: [Sep 30, **2015**, \NASA Selects Lucy Mission Concept, along with 4 other mission concepts, to receive funding for further study](http://lucy.swri.edu/timeline.html)

Comment: According to Scott Manley it was chosen as a target, and then named: https://youtu.be/zbwSSdtWUNE?t=285 .

Comment: @uhoh Even in this extensive podcast https://lockheedmartin.com/en-us/products/space-makers-podcast/space-makers-podcast-lucy-show-notes.html  and in this interview https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/2007/nasas-lucy-mission-a-journey-to-the-young-solar-system/ , both with the most involved scientists of the project, no mentioning of when Donaldjohanson was chosen. But because the proposal of the mission for NASA's Discovery Ptogram was submitted in Februariy 2015, I think 2014 is rhe right year.